# disable options in drop down based on certain selections javascript

Tags: javascript

So i am trying to disable certain dates in one drop down when a certain selection is made in an adjacent drop down. I have 20 pairs of these dropdowns. I can get this to work when it is only 1 pair but not both. So when "month1" is selected, i need certain options in the "day1" to not be available.

```
data = {
      disabled_days: {
        "June": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 17, 18, 24, 25, 31],
        "July": [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 15, 16, 22, 23, 29, 30],
        "August": [5, 6, 12, 13, 19, 20, 26, 27]
      }
    }
    //loop through to create this 20 times
    for(x=1;x<=20;x++){
    //get the select month box
    let select_month = document.querySelector('select[name="month'+x+'"]');

    //when month is selected
    select_month.addEventListener('change', function(e){

      //get the name of the month
      let month = select_month[select_month.selectedIndex].textContent;

      //get all the days in the data select box and enable them all
      let day_arr = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('select[name="day'+x+'"] option'))
      for(let day of day_arr) day.disabled = false;

      //loop over all the days to be disabled, find thme in the data ovject based on month and disable those days
      for (let disabled_day of data.disabled_days[month]){
        for (let day of day_arr){
          if (day.textContent == disabled_day) day.disabled = true;
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

So i think im faulting somewhere in my concatenation `('select[name="day'+x+'"] option')` and the same for the month. 
This has been messing me up for almost a week now so any help would really be appreciated.

Here is the php and html associated:

```
  <?php for($x=1; $x<=20; $x++){ ?>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label><?php echo "$x"; ?>.</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="month<?php echo $x ;?>">
                  <option selected disabled>- Month -</option>
                  <option value="06">June</option>
                  <option value="07">July</option>
                  <option value="08">August</option>
                </select>
                <select class="form-control" name="day<?php echo $x ;?>">
                  <option selected disabled>- Day -</option>
                  <option value="01">1</option>
                  <option value="02">2</option>
                  <option value="03">3</option>
                  <option value="04">4</option>
                  <option value="05">5</option>
                  <option value="06">6</option>
                  <option value="07">7</option>
                  <option value="08">8</option>
                  <option value="09">9</option>
                  <option value="10">10</option>
                  <option value="11">11</option>
                  <option value="12">12</option>
                  <option value="13">13</option>
                  <option value="14">14</option>
                  <option value="15">15</option>
                  <option value="16">16</option>
                  <option value="17">17</option>
                  <option value="18">18</option>
                  <option value="19">19</option>
                  <option value="20">20</option>
                  <option value="21">21</option>
                  <option value="22">22</option>
                  <option value="23">23</option>
                  <option value="24">24</option>
                  <option value="25">25</option>
                  <option value="26">26</option>
                  <option value="27">27</option>
                  <option value="28">28</option>
                  <option value="29">29</option>
                  <option value="30">30</option>
                  <option value="31">31</option>
                </select>
              </div> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What does the select section of the html look like?

Comment: Just edited my question and updated it with the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there are a few reasons why you would be experiencing issues with the drop-downs not correctly disabling:

First i noticed that the following call will return an empty array if the js code you provided is left as is:

`let select_month = document.querySelector('select[name="month'+x+'"]');`

This might change for you depending on how quickly your browser renders the DOM and runs the scripts, but generally speaking the select menu and options are not guaranteed to be loaded when you run the for loop. Therefore you should wrap the main for loop with  DOMContentLoaded event (code to follow), to ensure it only runs after the DOM is loaded. If you are using jQuery u can alternatively wrap the whole thing in a `$(document).ready(...)` function.

Secondly you can replace the following line:

`let day_arr = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('select[name="day'+x+'"] option'))`

With just:

`let day_arr = document.querySelectorAll('select[name="day'+idx+'"] option');`

`querySelectorAll` already returns an array you can iterate through. Also you will notice that I have the variable `idx` instead of `x`. That's due to the third and more confusing reason.

Variables declared with `var` in javascript are not block scoped (you can use `let` in es6 to avoid this), they are scoped to the function they are defined in, or otherwise globally scoped. That means that in your main for loop: `for(x=1;x<=20;x++)` the scope of the variable is not defined to be inside the for loop block, like it is with languages like c/c++, java, c#, its instead defined to be in the scope of the function which envelopes it. In this particular case there is no function enveloping it so it belonsg to the global object. So a consequence of that is the following:

When the for loop is run, it goes through the block and executes all the code, one of which is registering this event listener:

`select_month.addEventListener('change', function(e){})`

This event listener is an asynchronous call, meaning its not executed when the for loop is run, its only declared and registered to an event. This means that when it is finally run, after a change event, the for loop has long since completed. But this change event function has a reference to `x` in the following line :

`document.querySelectorAll('select[name="day'+x+'"] option')`

When it does finally run this bit of code, its getting the value of x at the current time, well after the for loop has completed, which means its value is `21`. It has access to the `x` value after the loop has completed because, as we discussed, the variable is not scoped to the for loop, it exists outside of it. So `x` will be `21` for all calls to this event, regardless of which drop-down you selected. Since `21` not part of a valid day name, the array will always be empty.

The solution to this is to wrap the change event call inside its own function, and pass the value of `x` to this new function as a parameter, lets call it `idx`. This function will be declared and executed immediately. Note that even though the function is run, the change event is still only registered, not executed. Now the querySelector statement will reference the function parameter instead of the `x` variable. Since the function parameter is executed for each loop, its passed in a new value of `x` each time, therefore the parameter is also new for each change event listener. You may have seen this pattern before, its called a closure.

I've updated you code, take a look:

```
var data = {
  disabled_days: {
    "June": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 17, 18, 24, 25, 31],
    "July": [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 15, 16, 22, 23, 29, 30],
    "August": [5, 6, 12, 13, 19, 20, 26, 27]
  }
}
//On DOM Loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    //loop through to create this 20 times
    for(x=1;x<=20;x++){
        //get the select month box
        let select_month = document.querySelector('select[name="month'+x+'"]');

        //A colusure to wrap the change event listener, this is done
        //to pass the current value of x into the listener
        (function(idx){
          //when month is selected
          select_month.addEventListener('change', function(e){

            //get the name of the month
            let month = select_month[select_month.selectedIndex].textContent;

            //get all the days in the data select box and enable them all
            let day_arr = document.querySelectorAll('select[name="day'+idx+'"] option');

            for(let day of day_arr) day.disabled = false;

            //loop over all the days to be disabled, find thme in the data ovject based on month and disable those days
            for (let disabled_day of data.disabled_days[month]){
                for (let day of day_arr){
                    if (day.textContent == disabled_day) day.disabled = true;
                }
            }    
          })
        })(x);
    }
});
```

On a final note, you should really rethink the logic you have in your code. There's a lot of inefficient and unnecessary parts to it, particularly in the event listener.  You are currently calling 2 for-loops, with one of them being nested, each time a month is selected on any of the 20 drop-downs. There is no need to do that, you should just disable the relevant options once when the DOM is loaded and never have to loop though it on the change event. You have to consider the state of your data and the events that alter it; selecting the month drop-down has no impact on the disabled days object, therefore you should not have to update any elements that rely on this data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I have been working with C++ and Java in school a lot recently so that might be why i tried using the for loop like that. Definitely a lot I have to learn still but I appreciate all the advice you gave me. I didnt know to use the closure at all. I will reference this code a quite a bit i feel. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.